# MultiFiltering with JQuery and Data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to make a multi filter using the data attribute on a div,JQuery, and check boxes. When a checkbox is selected I want JQuery to remove the elements on the screen that's data attribute doesn't contain all the selected items.

For example of one check box' values = 'mens' and the other is 'metal' then the elements on the screen that do not match those will fade or hide.

Here is a sample div with the data attrbute:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 shop-grid-item" id="BSG016BK" data-attributes='["men's","wayfarer","metal","134","133","black","black"]'></div>
```

And the filtering block includes:

```
<div class="information-blocks">
                    <div class="block-title size-2">Gender</div>
                    <label class="checkbox-entry">
                        <input type="checkbox" value="men's" class="filter" name="filter[]" /> <span class="check"></span> Men's
                    </label>
                    <label class="checkbox-entry">
                        <input type="checkbox" value="women's" class="filter" name="filter[]" /> <span class="check"></span> Women's
                    </label>
                    <label class="checkbox-entry">
                        <input type="checkbox" value="unisex" class="filter" name="filter[]" /> <span class="check"></span> Unisex
                    </label>
            </div>
            <div class="information-blocks">
                <div class="block-title size-2">Frame Material </div>
                <label class="checkbox-entry">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="metal" class="filter" name="filter[]" /> <span class="check"></span> Metal Frames
                </label>
                <label class="checkbox-entry">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="plastic" class="filter" name="filter[]" /> <span class="check"></span> Plastic Frames
                </label>
                <label class="checkbox-entry">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="wood" class="filter" name="filter[]" /> <span class="check"></span> Wood Frames
                </label>
            </div>
```

I am using:

```
$('.filter').on('click',function(){
            //
});
```

to capture the selection values but I am not sure how to collect all those that are currently selected and then use that list to start to remove the items from the divs that do not contain those values in the data attribute.

Any help would be greatly appreciated or let point me in the right direction. I have been looking at tutorials and other libraries but I don't see anything that allows me to use multiple sources and filter out on the data attribute instead of a class.

Comment: Here a working jQuery https://jsfiddle.net/tdxzzpwt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you must change your ***shop-grid-item*** attribute to look like this :

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 shop-grid-item" id="BSG016BK" data-attributes="['men\'s','wayfarer','metal','134','133','black','black']">
</div>
```

After that, you just need to get the appropriated ***data-attribute*** and compare with your filters.

Here a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t64ys5La/) that show in console the attributes as an array.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I fixed the data attribute. Only question is that I have multiple items looping with the .shop-grid-item class for each item. Should I use an $.each for each items, check to see if the items selected match the items in the data attribute and then hide them if they are not there. If so, is there a way I can collect all the items from the different check boxes to make a list of words to filter on from the '.filter' check boxes?

Comment: looking to your code yes a $.each will be necessary. you check a boxe and loop on all your items. I think the best is to allow user to check multiple boxes and apply it with a button ( for performance issue )